# Node.js on AWS Lambda: UnstructuredLoader in LangChain Throws ENOENT Error with Valid API Key

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, langchain, pinecone

I'm encountering a challenging issue with the `UnstructuredLoader` from the LangChain library in a Node.js application running on AWS Lambda. Despite providing a valid API key, the loader throws an ENOENT error, indicating an invalid API key.

**Here's the error log:**

```
2023-12-05T14:20:10.745Z    9482936f-6dd0-5bc7-99ce-ce865e1eb340    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Failed to partition file /tmp/README.md with error 401 and message {\"detail\":\"API key is invalid, please provide a valid API key in the header.\"}",
    "stack": [
        "Error: Failed to partition file /tmp/README.md with error 401 and message {\"detail\":\"API key is invalid, please provide a valid API key in the header.\"}",
        "    at UnstructuredLoader._partition (/var/task/node_modules/langchain/dist/document_loaders/fs/unstructured.cjs:189:19)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
        "    at async UnstructuredLoader.load (/var/task/node_modules/langchain/dist/document_loaders/fs/unstructured.cjs:198:26)",
        "    at async processFile (/var/task/index.js:103:21)",
        "    at async Runtime.handler (/var/task/index.js:151:5)"
    ]
}
```

The issue arises specifically when using the UnstructuredLoader for processing file types that are not natively supported by other loaders in LangChain (e.g., PPTX files). I have confirmed that the API key is correctly set in the environment variables and works fine for other loaders.

**Here's a relevant snippet of the implementation:**

```
async function processFile(filename: string, key: string) {
  try {
    // Fetch the File content from S3 using the new method
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: filename,
    });
    const content: any = await s3Client.send(command);

    const tempFilePath = path.join('/tmp', path.basename(filename));
    await fs.writeFile(tempFilePath, content.Body); // Directly save the buffer

    // Load and split the File
    const fileExtension = path.extname(tempFilePath).toLowerCase();
    let loader: any;
    switch (fileExtension) {
      ...
      default:
        loader = new UnstructuredLoader(tempFilePath, { apiKey: key });
    }
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error processing and ingesting File: ${filename}. Error: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I've ensured that the API key is being passed correctly to the `UnstructuredLoader`. This setup works flawlessly for other file types but not for those requiring the `UnstructuredLoader`. Is there something I'm missing in the configuration or usage of the `UnstructuredLoader`? Any insights or experiences with similar issues would be immensely helpful.